# docker compose inside docker in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

**What I have:**
I am creating a Jenkins(BlueOcean Pipeline) for CI/CD. I am using the docker in docker approach to use Jenkins as described in the [Jenkins docs tutorail](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/create-a-pipeline-in-blue-ocean/#run-jenkins-in-docker).
I have tested the setup, it is working fine. I can build and run docker images in the Jenkins container. Now, I am trying to use `docker-compose, but it says` docker-compose: not found
`

**Problem:**

Unable to use `docker-compose inside the container(Jenkins).

**What I want:**
I want to able to use `docker-compose inside the container using the dind(docker in docker) approach.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it from the question, have you installed `docker-compose` or not? It's usually installed separately from Docker. See [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Comment: I am using the docker container inside the docker approach. The whole approach can be found in the official Jenkins article link attached to the question.

Comment: And yes `docker-compose` is installed locally but it is not available inside the container.

Comment: Things installed locally do no appear in containers on their own. You can attempt mounting it inside but it's best to install it in container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8

USER root

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y curl

# Install Docker

RUN curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz | tar xvz -C /tmp/ && mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker

# Install Docker Compose

RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose

# Here your customizations...
```

Comment: So you have added these scripts to install docker-compose at the start of your `dockerCompose` file. Right ?

Comment: Exactly, so each Jenkins build can execute docker and compose inside its own  docker image. I use that approach since many time.

Comment: Is this approach good? And also are you using Jenkins inside a docker container like the approach I mentioned in the article in my question ?

Comment: Moreover, I am able to use `docker` inside the container to build docker images. But the issue is only with `docker-compose`. So by your approach, I will have to only add docker compose script.

Comment: I have a docker instance build upon a its official docker image. Each Jenkins pipeline generate its own docker image, and inside that I install docker and docker-compose to serve my custom building logic.

Comment: Okay, I think this approach doesn't work for me. If add these script in my `dockerCompose` file, how will I be able to `compose up` the `dockerCompose` file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `docker-compose` is not installed in that machine.
You can check if `docker-compose` is installed or not using `docker-compose --version`.
 If it is not installed then you can install it in below way :

1. Using apt- package manager : `sudo apt install -y docker-compose`
   OR
2. Using python install manager : `sudo pip install docker-compose`

Comment: `docker-compose is installed locally at my machine.